# SELECT MAX date and its quantity and SUM quantity for that date

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am using Oracle 11g. let say I have a delivery table as below.
The example below shows that the latest date is 7/11/2019 and the item is delivered twice with different quantity.
How to get the latest date (max date) and its quantity and also the sum of the quantity? 
[image]

I have tried and I get the result of max date and max quantity. But not the sum of the max qty.

```
SELECT DISTINCT k.item_no, 
MAX(k.date) OVER(PARTITION BY k.item_no) AS LATEST_DEL_DATE,
MAX(k.qty) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY k.date DESC NULLS LAST) 
OVER(PARTITION BY k.item_no) AS LATEST_QUANTITY
FROM DEL k, DELCONFIRM h, ITEM o
where k.code_no=h.code_no
and k.item_no=o.item_no
AND k.qty<> 0
and k.item_no='123'
;
```

I want the output result to look something like

[image: EXPECTED RESULT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an analytical function (`DENSE_RANK`) as follows:

```
SELECT
    ITEM_NO,
    DATE   AS LATEST_DEL_DATE,
    SUM(QTY) AS TOTAL_QTY
FROM
    (  SELECT DISTINCT
            K.item_NO,
            K.QTY,
            K.DATE,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER(
                PARTITION BY K.item_NO
                ORDER BY K.DATE DESC NULLS LAST
            ) AS DR
        FROM
            DEL K 
            JOIN  DELCONFIRM H ON (K.code_NO = H.code_NO)
            JOIN ITEM O ON (K.item_NO = O.item_NO)
            WHERE K.QTY <> 0
            AND K.GOO_NO = '123'
    )
WHERE DR = 1
GROUP BY ITEM_NO, DATE;
```

**Note:** Use standard ANSI joins as shown in the aforementioned query.

Cheers!!

Comment: I tried the coding and it works, however why does the the quantity from your coding is different from Nick? The date is the same except the quantity. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: What is the difference? Can you please show me here?

Comment: it is hard to copy the code here, probably beacuse I tried both of the code from you and Nick on an actual data.

Comment: For itemcode 123, what different output you received ??

Comment: I implement both of the code in my project and the quantity differs between yours and Nick.

Comment: Ok. Then which one is correct? I may not be able to help untill I have the idea of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` the delivery table to derived table of the latest delivery date for the item of interest and then `SUM` the delivered quantities for that date:

```
SELECT m.item_code, 
       m.max_date AS "Latest_delivery_date",  
       SUM(d1.quantity) AS "Total_delivered"
FROM (SELECT item_code, MAX(date) AS max_date
      FROM delivery
      WHERE item_code = 123) m
JOIN delivery d1 ON d1.item_code = m.item_code AND d1.date = m.max_date
GROUP BY m.item_code, m.max_date
```

Output:

```
item_code   Latest_delivery_date    Total_delivered
123         2019-11-07              17
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=10e39932cc96c330fa84fa02c55ec51c)

Comment: I used your code and try it to mine, but it doesn't work.

Comment: it says that ORA-00937: not a single-group group function on line "FROM (SELECT k.item_no, MAX(k.kdate) AS max_date"

Comment: @newbeginnner you need to add a `GROUP BY k.goo_no` to the subquery. Apologies - my original demo was on MySQL and I have updated it for Oracle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e4b91efb782614eaf44aa1cedd6ef77f

Comment: I tried the coding and it works, however why does the the quantity from your coding is different from Tejash? The date is the same except the quantity. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @newbeginnner I don't know... both of our codes give the same result for your demo data https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a6839bc16b031dc3d3c0eb3b55ec8f85 so without trying them on actual data I can't really offer any idea why the results would be different. Perhaps you could try focusing on one particular date where the results are different and doing the calculation manually to see which is correct.

Comment: I see, probably because I tried on the actual data hence the result is difference. THANK YOU SIR

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation and a window function:

```
select id.*
from (select k.item_code, k.date, sum(k.qty) as sum(qty),
             row_number() over (partition by k.item_code order by k.date desc) as seqnum
      from Del k join
           Delconfirm h
           on k.seq_no = h.seq_no join 
           ITEM o
           on k.item_no = o.item_no
      where  k.QTY <> 0 and
            k.item_no = '123'
      group by k.item_no
     ) id
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note in particular the use of proper, explicit, *standard* `JOIN` syntax.  **Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.**

Comment: I tried your code, but why does it says "FROM keyword not found where expected"
on the second line?

Comment: why never use commas?

Comment: @newbeginnner . . . `JOIN` is the proper syntax.  It is more powerful and it has been around since the 1990s.  Commas never should have been introduced but that is ancient history, as far as computing goes.  There is no obvious syntax problem in the query.

Comment: joining by using a  comma ease me as I get confuse with join syntax. Inner join, Outer join, right join etc. Anyway, thank you